# im aware that solving the same intergral may give different equations as answers but how do i verify if my equation is correct?

Tags: integration, self-learning

i used to substitute a value into the actual book prescribed answer and the into the answer i got to see if the equations yield the same answer. i now want to confirm if the method i am using is legitimate.

this is my solution to the question

[image]

this is the book solution

[image]

Comment: Your initial formula has a 2. There’s has 4. The integral of $-4dt$ should be $-4t$ not $-4x$.

Comment: For the sake of better writing, you have to be consistent with your notations. Saying "$\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x+2}} = \int \frac{2\left(t^2 - 2\right)}{???}dt$" is incorrect and is a sloppy way of proceeding from one step to the next. It's not just you, but my pet peeve is when people lazily leave out symbols assuming whoever is reading their work would understand it (e.g. writing $\frac{x^2}{2} = x$ because the derivative of $\frac{x^2}{2}$ is $x$).

Answer (score 0):

If we fix the value error in your integral, we get
$$\int\frac x{\sqrt{x+4}}\,dx$$
And your substitution becomes $t^2 = x + 4$ and $x = t^2 - 4$. Let's explicitly add the condition that $t > 0$, as that is all that is needed to cover all values of $x$. You still get $dx = 2t\,dt$.

Let's be a bit clearer about how this substitution goes than you were:
$$\int\frac x{\sqrt{x+4}}\,dx = \int \frac{(t^2 - 4)}{\sqrt{t^2}}(2t\,dt)= \int 2t^2 - 8\,dt = \frac23t^3 - 8t + C$$

(You may not understand why yet, but that $+\,C$ on the end is important. Don't leave it off.)

Now you stop here, as if you were done. You are not. The original integral is in $x$, not $t$. You need to transform it back to $x$ by $t = \sqrt{x+4}$
$$\int\frac x{\sqrt{x+4}}\,dx = \frac23(\sqrt{x+4})^3 - 8\sqrt{x+4} + C$$

Still looks different from the book's answer. But it isn't different. However, I am going to leave it to you to explore why. Now it is strictly an algebra problem.